# Resources loads in IDE but not in Runnable JAR

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I'm trying to load a font and when I run it in eclipse it works fine. But once I export it to JAR the font is non-existent.

I've tried `ClassLoader`, `File`, and `getResources`. None of them work in the JAR.

Here's the code I'm currently using:

```
try {
    pixelFont = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new File("res/fonts/pixel.ttf")).deriveFont(40f);
    GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
    ge.registerFont(Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new File("res/fonts/pixel.ttf")));
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch(FontFormatException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Show your code where you tried to load font.

Answer (score 0):

In Export Jar dialog make sure you select all the resources you need. If you do there will be no problem and all the resources will be add to your jar file.

See [this tutorial](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/~scottm/cs307/handouts/Eclipse%20Help/jarInEclipse.htm) if you have any problem.

Also if you want to make sure that your resources are there, just unzip you jar file and it must contain your resources.